# What to do if a user is editing tags in a lot of my questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, etiquette

Recently I noticed that [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/518955/robert-levy) has deleted the tag `microsoft-surface` in a lot of my questions that are about [Microsoft Surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Surface):

- [Path Markup Syntax in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629524/path-markup-syntax-in-wpf)
- [How to find a Element in a Grid that is in the same row and the next colum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566567/how-to-find-a-element-in-a-grid-that-is-in-the-same-row-and-the-next-colum)
- [How to generate a PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545872/how-to-generate-a-pdf)
- [WPF: Canvas and zIndex? How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393074/wpf-canvas-and-zindex-how-does-it-work)
- [How do draw FormattedText (if not in the onRender method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330722/how-do-draw-formattedtext-if-not-in-the-onrender-method)
- [How to find a point that is on the same circle given an angle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044214/how-to-find-a-point-that-is-on-the-same-circle-given-an-angle)

All these questions are about my Microsoft Surface application. Naturally some of them are also more general, but I think with the tag `microsoft-surface` it is obvious that the question is specifically for Microsoft Surface.

What's the standard procedure here? I don't have time to check all my questions and do a rollback.

Comment: If you want them back, just roll back.

Comment: @Gamecat well, there must have been some reason for the user to remove them. Wasn't there some discussion about Surface a while ago? (Can't find any though)

Comment: A random other question, [Easiest way to check if an arbitrary String is a valid filename](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650462/easiest-way-to-check-if-an-arbitrary-string-is-a-valid-filename) did not seem to be specific for Microsoft Surface though? Are you sure the others really would get different answers with that tag?

Comment: Not really, but since it was for a Microsoft Surface Application I added the tag, because I thought maybe there is a platform specific better solution for the questiosn. Ok maybe not for the String question, but for the other 5 listed above.

Comment: Okay, let's see if Robert can respond here. (Note that you can use [@reply comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to notify a user who edited your post. I meanwhile did that in your first example.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, I removed the Surface tag from these because there is nothing Surface-specific in the questions or in their answers.  They aren't of special interest to anyone following or searching for Surface information.  You had a couple of others that I spotted while cleaning up that tag which were questionable, but I left them.

It may be helpful for you to understand that the Surface APIs (which I designed, BTW) are merely a set of input events and extra UI controls.  Aside from those features, everything on Surface is standard to WPF, .NET, C#, and Windows Vista.  Your questions on those more general technologies are good ones, and may be helpful to a much larger audience than just people targeting Surface.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your answer. I just added the tag so that others see it is in Surface, because I often didn't know if Ishould use the general solution (WPF) or if there is maybe a Surface-specific solution for my problem.

Answer (score 14):

1. **Remember that 3rd-party editors are generally trying to help.** There's no real reward for it, apart from seeing the site improved (and maybe a badge or two).
2. **Consider that you may be choosing poor tags.** You may actually get better answers by not artificially limiting the scope of your questions... In your case, it's not entirely clear how MS Surface is relevant.
3. **Consider that you may not have made it clear *in your question* why a given tag is relevant.** Again, what about Surface makes generating PDFs in C# different from normal versions of Windows (or any other C#-supported platform)? Is there a reason that answers to previous (non-Surface-specific) questions on the topic didn't work for you?
4. **You can roll back changes with a single click** (and you'll be notified of any edits via that little envelope next to your name, making it even easier).
5. **If the problem persists/becomes too large in scope, flag one of your questions for moderator attention** and ask them to resolve it. Be prepared to abide by their decision.
6. **Ask about the tags here on Meta** if the moderator disagrees. We'll set you straight.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say the edits were fair enough because the questions themselves and the techniques you're using aren't Surface specific.

Perhaps "[WPF: Canvas and zIndex? How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393074/wpf-canvas-and-zindex-how-does-it-work)" is borderline because you're using a `<s:SurfaceWindow/>` window, but only if you screw your eye's up, because ultimately you're just working with a regular `<Grid>` object.

I think it'd be sufficient to mention in passing, in the question, that you're writing code for surface devices just in case there's a small chance that may be relevant. Otherwise, for people who are actively following the surface tag, your questions which aren't surface specific, clutter their feed.